# How do I know how much time was given to me to stay in the USA?

Tags: visas, usa

I came in the USA on a 10 year multiple visa. On February 5, 2016 the immigration officer didn't stamp how long I can be in the USA. How do I know how much time I have to stay in the USA?

Comment: Was anything else written on your admission stamp?

Answer (score 8):

The immigration officer should have written/stamped the date on your passport, however if they didn't you can find the details on your I94 record on the CBP website at http://www.cbp.gov/i94

Answer (score 0):

The I-94 is [electronic](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/). They also usually stamp the Admit Until date of the I-94 underneath the entry stamp for your convenience (so you don't have to look it up online), but sometimes they forget. In any case, it's the I-94 that's authoritative. (It's always a good idea to look up the I-94 anyway, because sometimes the dates don't match.)